# Why is my method only reading one line of text?

Tags: java, text

I have a method that would read parts of a text file that has 4 parts: date, name, description and amount like

```
4/5/2018, gel, hair product, 20.00
4/4/2018, wax, hair product, 20.00
```

and so on...

My problem is that my method would only read the 1st line and then output my catch method saying that the file isn't found.

```
public static void showRecordedExpense(String filename)throws IOException {
    String date = "";
    String name = "";
    String description = "";
    double amount = 0.00;
     try{
         Scanner read = new Scanner(new File(filename));
         while (read.hasNextLine()){
             String oneLine = read.nextLine();
             String[] parts = oneLine.split(",");
             try {
                 date = parts[0];
                 name = parts[1];
                 description = parts[2];
                 amount = Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);
                 System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%20s%n", "---------------", "---------------",
                         "---------------", "---------------------");
                 System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%31s%n","Date", "Name", "Description","Amount");
                 System.out.printf("%15s%14s%33s%15s%n",date,name,description,amount);
                 System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%20s%n", "---------------", "---------------",
                         "---------------", "---------------------");
             }catch (Exception e){
                 System.out.println("no");
             } finally {
                 read.close();
             }
         }
     }catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println("The file could not be found");
     }

}
```

EDIT:
Taking out the finally worked.

Comment: Where is your file stored? What is the value of `filename`?

Comment: my file is stored within Intellij's src, the name is expenses.txt

Comment: You are closing Scanner after it reads the first line in `finally`

Comment: @JoeyDeguzman : What is the value of `filename`?

Comment: @NicholasK you are using Scanner to read the file and `finally` executes after your very first inner `try/catch` statement closing the Scanner, then when your `while` loop iterates it can no longer read...

Comment: You're hiding the exception type, message and stack trace, which would tell you what the problem is. Don't catch Exception. Catch the exception that you expect, and that you can handle corrreectly. Print the stack traces of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) for details on how `finally` works. You are currently closing your Scanner at the end of your first iteration of the `while` loop due to the `finally` you paired with your `try/catch`. The next iteration of the `while` can no longer read from the file since you closed it, which is why it's only reading the first line. Consider taking out the finally and just closing the Scanner once the `while` loop is complete.

```
     try{
         Scanner read = new Scanner(new File(filename));
         while (read.hasNextLine()){
             String oneLine = read.nextLine();
             String[] parts = oneLine.split(",");
             try {
                 date = parts[0];
                 name = parts[1];
                 description = parts[2];
                 amount = Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);
                 System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%20s%n", "---------------", "---------------",
                         "---------------", "---------------------");
                 System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%31s%n","Date", "Name", "Description","Amount");
                 System.out.printf("%15s%14s%33s%15s%n",date,name,description,amount);
                 System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%20s%n", "---------------", "---------------",
                         "---------------", "---------------------");
             }catch (Exception e){
                 System.out.println("no");
             }
         }

         read.close();
     }catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println("The file could not be found");
     }
```